# Numerical simulation

Tags: random, simulation

I want to generate a numerical simulation in table for an equational output. I have used following code. But somehow I can't get any output. I am very novice to Mathematica. Can anyone please recommend what change I should make?

````
Subscript[r, 1] := (-2 Subscript[c, 1] + \[Gamma] Subscript[c, 
   2] - (-2 + \[Gamma]) (-a + \[Tau] + (2 + \[Gamma]) ((\[Tau] - \
\[Tau] Subscript[\[Rho], 1])/(v \[Theta] Subscript[\[Rho], 1]))^(
      1/(-1 + v))))/(-4 + \[Gamma]^2)
simStep := 
 Module[{\[Gamma], Subscript[\[Rho], 1], 
   v, \[Theta], \[Tau]}, {\[Gamma], Subscript[\[Rho], 1]} = 
   RandomReal[1, 2];
  {\[Theta]} = 2;
  {\[Tau]} = 1;
  {v} = {2};
  {\[Gamma]} = 0.5;
  {Subscript[c, 1]} = 1;
  {Subscript[c, 2]} = 1;
  {Subscript[\[Rho], 1], Subscript[r, 1]}]


```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a lot of red ink.  Try to simplify.  Avoid complicated notations.  The most useful formula: `f1[x_,y_]:=f2[x,y]` where `f2` must not call `f1` to avoid recursion (unless you want it).

Don't use `Module` for grouping, use parenthesis.

Example:

```
Clear@f1;f1[x_,y_]:=(Print@x;x+2 y)

f1[2,3]
```

; suppresses output.

If you need double output use a list:

```
Clear@f1; f1[x_, y_] := {x + 1, x^2}
```

Test each step before going to the next.

```
Clear@f2; f2@{x_, y_} := x - y

f2[2,3]

f2@{2, 3}

f2@f1[2, 3]
```

`f@x` is the same as `f[x]`.  `Clear` is to be sure to start with a clean symbol.

Comment: Is there any serious reason to use parenthesis instead of `Module` or `Block`? Or do you recommend it simply because it is lighter?

Comment: I just use the simplest structure that is necessary. Simple means easy to read and not using computer resources. `Module[{},x;y]` is same as `(x;y)`, `Module[{var},x]` introduces a new variable each time it is used.  I almost never introduce variables, I use constants, introduced by `With`.  The instructions I gave are probably sufficient to use Mathematica as a programmable calculator like the ones used at school.